# Why does my C program print new blank lines when I try to print a string in the reverse order?

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to make a program which returns the a number and a string with the elements in reverse order. I was able to do both, but I don't understand why there are some blank new lines when I print out the reversed string

I've also tried it with just a single word using the scanf function, and a blank line still appears

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char s[50];
   int i, n, lastDigit, textLen=0;

   printf("Enter a number: ");
   scanf("%i", &n);
   getchar();

   printf("Enter the text: ");
   fgets(s, 50, stdin);

   printf("The reversed number is: ");

   while(n > 0){
    lastDigit = n%10;
    n=n/10;
    printf("\n%i", lastDigit);
   }

    printf("\nThe reversed text is: ");

     while(s[textLen] != '\0'){
        textLen++;
    }

   for(i=textLen; i>=0; i--){
    printf("\n%c", s[i]);
   }

return 0;
}
```

I expect:
T
e
s
t
But the actual output is:

T
e
s
t

Comment: OT: regarding the calculation of `textLen`, The function: `strlen()` exposed by the `string.h` header file, is made for this calculation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual page of [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters from stream
>   and stores them into the `buffer` pointed to by s. Reading stops after
>   an `EOF` or a `newline`. **If a `newline` is read, it is stored into the
>   buffer**.
>   So here

```
char s[50];
fgets(s, 50, stdin);
```

`fgets()` stores the *newline character* at the end of buffer `s` if it was read. To remove this trailing `\n` character use `strcspn()`. For e.g

```
char s[50] = {}; /* Initialize it */
fgets(s, 50, stdin); 
s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = 0; /* remove the trailing \n */
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me. I got rid of the extra lines and was left only with one, which came from the last character of the string which was the null character, and also the first one to be printed. Subtracting 1 from textLen in the for loop solved this problem too, and there are no extra lines anymore.

Answer (score 1):

`textLen` is the number of characters in string `s`.  The first character printed is `s[textLen]`, which is the NUL character at the end.

Comment: Thank you, reducing the length of the string by 1 in the for loop removed the first extra line.